# Удаление дубликатов в отсортированном Vector с условием С++

Tags: c++, vector

У меня есть вектор структур. Я хочу убрать дубликаты структур из этого вектора но убрать только те структуры у которых index != "H".
Для удаления дубликатов использую bool operator. А вот по условию index != "H" не знаю как сделать. Подскажите пожалуста.

```
    typedef struct aspect {
    string index;
    string type;
    string drob;
    double d_aspect;
    string s_aspect;
}asp;

    bool operator==(const asp& a, const asp& b)
{
    return a.d_aspect == b.d_aspect;
}

    sort(aspectFile.begin(), aspectFile.end(), cmp);

    aspectFile.resize(unique(aspectFile.begin(), aspectFile.end()) - aspectFile.begin());
```

Answer (score 0):

используйте remove_if

```
 bool is_H(const asp& a) { return a.index=="H"; } // условие удаления

 aspectFile.erase( std::remove_if( aspectFile.begin(), aspectFile.end() ), aspectFile.end() );
```

Список стандартных алгоритмов (функций работающих с итераторами): https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm

Comment: aspectFile.erase(std::remove_if(aspectFile.begin(), aspectFile.end(), [](const asp& a) {a.index != "H"; }), aspectFile.end()); У меня чтото не работает. [](const asp& a) {a.index != "H"; }) Пустоой указатель

Comment: Это работает только дубликаты остаются  aspectFile.erase(std::remove_if(aspectFile.begin(), aspectFile.end(), [](const asp & a) { return a.index == "H"; }), aspectFile.end());

Comment: А как a функцию bool is_H() добавить сравнение значения текущей и последующих полей d_aspect  Чтото никик!